# DIV behave like an IFRAME & load url using ajax

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, html

DIV behave like an IFRAME & load url using ajax for a web application having many forms/web pages loading each form/webpages dynamically

Comment: I need to load the webpages/forms dynamically using ajax

Comment: I think it needs clarification - what exactly do you need, what feature of IFRAMEs would you like to replicate? For all we know, you may just want to put scrollbars on DIVs, so they'll look a little like IFRAMEs. 

Btw, you can load IFRAMEs dynamically - as in, create them dynamically, change their address to something you need (say, an ajax - or even ahah call address), etc. Again, what do you mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A div can't behave exactly like an IFrame - An IFrame has it's own javascript environment, but a div shares the environment with the parent window.

However, you can make an ajax request to a url, and insert the response into a div.

I suggest using jQuery, they have a simple function [$.get(url)](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get) for this.